# EBPI class for PageInfo

Tags: c#, com-interop

I'm using Global360's libraries to interface with their system in C#.  I need to access the `PageInfo` class accessible via

```
public virtual object Page(int lPage)
  Member of MosaixDoc.ImageDocumentClass
```

Unfortunately the return type is object, and I can't seem to find a `PageInfo` class or interface in the libraries.

Is there a interface that I'm missing?  If not, can I access this object's methods using some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do firstly is install the BPI client software from your server to be able to log in. I am coding in C# and include the Process Agent install files to avoid using `CreateObject()`, if you want to use VB .Net you only have to install the **EBPI Client**, you will note that the

> **Start->Programs->Process360 9.5**

icons point to the server the **Setup.exe** was run from.

The dll's provided by Global360 are COM Wrappers, when you call them you also need to release the resources, example:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(object);
```

The most common dll's you need to reference are;

**Global360.MxBase.Interop.dll**

**Global360.MxDoc.Interop.dll**

**Global360.MxLib.Interop.dll**

**Global360.MxMkup.Interop.dll**

The `PageInfo` class resides in `MosaixMarkups.PageInfo`, the dll for that is **Global360.MxMkup.Interop**.

In C# you would use `MosaixDoc.ImageDocument.get_PageInfo(int page);`

Would you like the API Guide?

Comment: I have the API, just didn't realize `PageInfo` was in `Markups`.  Thanks!